# Error message - folder too large to download

Tags: windows-7, download, dropbox

I`m trying to download everything I put on Dropbox to filter out copied etc. I have downloaded a folder, no problem, but another folder and I get the message that the folder is too large to download. Do I now need to download every file?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are accessing Dropbox through its website (rather than through the app): folders larger than either 1GB or 10,000 files cannot be downloaded this way.

> It's not possible to use the website to download an entire folder that's over 1 GB or that has over 10,000 files. If the folder is in your account, use the Dropbox  desktop application to download the entire folder to your computer automatically.

(From https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/49.)

You will have to either split your download into multiple attempts or switch to using the Dropbox app.

Answer (score -2):

Your hard drive is not big enough to fit everything you've stored on Dropbox.com

- You can either download everything to a bigger hard drive
- Perform your duplicate filtering online on Dropbox
- Use a trial of Beyond Compare 4.0 and view in flat structure where all duplicate files will appear. Your left column and right column will both have to be Dropbox.